# "There is no builder hero in the team." What is a builder hero?

Tags: overwatch

There is a Team Tip before the game starts saying

> There is no builder hero in the team.

According to the [official website](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/), there are only 4 character classes:

1. Offense
2. Defense
3. Tank
4. Support

[image: 4 classes]

I guess that builder is a sub-class of support, but **what is a builder hero exactly?**

Is there an official source or a wiki article to read about this topic? Can someone list all the builder heroes?

Comment: Side note since this was bumped to the main page:  The notice about Builder Heroes hasn't been in the game for some time now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Torbjörn and Symmetra are the builders.  They build turrets.  This is what the warning message is referencing.

Comment: And only those two ?

Comment: Currently, I believe these are the only two who fill that role.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you see the warning for 'No Snipers' on defense, Only Hanzo and Widowmaker fill those roles.

Comment: Yeah, seems really weird to have team tips for a role that can only be filled by such niche heroes. Maybe this tip only shows up on Defense maps?